# Stability for linear discrete Systems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, discrete-time

As I know, for a linear continuous time system to be stable, it has to have negative real part eigenvalues. But for discrete systems, it is okay to have also plus values as long as the complex eigenvalues are within the unit circle. That is $\sqrt{Re(\lambda)+Im(\lambda)}<1$. I dont understand why this is the case with discrete systems, maybe someone can help. Thanks

Comment: For continuous, solutions involve $e^{i\lambda t}$; for discrete, $\lambda^t$. So continuous is stable if real part negative, discrete is stable if modulus less than one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, can you please elaborate why for discrete $\lambda^t$ ?

Comment: If $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A^nx=\lambda^nx$.

Comment: So are we OK now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thank you! :)